# Mobile Phones confused about BLE pairing

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

We have an IoT device that has an onboard BLE chip (Anaren A20737A) that the user can control from their mobile phone.  At times, the phone will pair with the device (or at least report that it is paired), but will not receive any data, and all commands appear to be ignored by the device.  Connecting the logger to the device, we can see that it believes that it is sending out messages correctly, and that it is paired with the phone.  The solution appears to be forgetting the BLE pairing from the Bluetooth settings on the phone, and sometimes restarting the phone as well.  No changes to the IoT device appear to have any impact, the only thing that works is forgetting the pairing from the phone's settings.  This problem has occurred on both iPhone and Android (separate code bases).

**EDIT**

The problem is seen on iOS 7.0 and multiple versions of android from at least 4.4 onward.

Logging the data out from the chip we see it drop the connection and start advertising.  About 1 in 10 times, the phone seems to believe that it has a connection with the device, but the logs on the device show that it is still in advertising mode.

Has anyone else ever seen this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. 1. Have you reached out to the manufacturer. 2. You didn't mention OS versions. Given that the problem is occurring with both iPhone and Android I'm still leaning toward something in your implementation (if it was just Android, that would be more 'understandable' due to variety of manufacturers) unless it works fine until it gets into customer hands. 3. If customers are reporting this - any environmental factors: i.e. intermittent radio noise

Comment: I will edit the question to include more information.